# Google Spreadsheet Script to selectively protect certain cells?

Tags: google-apps-script

Long time viewer of this site, first time poster.

I have [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q2MAe3SI_Sj7-ieUF95fkgxOUuSRRgV1sifxYEwCJ3w/edit#gid=0) that is public and runs off of crowd sourced information.

Every time a new person enters data, I like to protect the data they have submitted so that is not erased or changed by others. This has proved to be a somewhat lengthy task once a good bit of data has been added.

My question is, is there a script that I can run that works like: if value in any cell > 0, then protect cell?

This would allow me to open up the spreadsheet and see that all the values entered are legitimate, then protect all the cells with values with one click.

Thanks in advance!
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to manipulate the 'Protect Range' with Google Apps script. There's currently an open issue with this [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721), which you should star for traction and to receive updates on if this is resolved.

Currently you can only protect an [entire page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/page-protection), which looking at your sheet, won't do you much good I think.